# TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame openni_depth_optical_frame

Tags: ros, rosbag, tf2-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to play my bagfile with the -l loop parameter. However after the time is reset, I get a lot of these errors:

```
Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame openni_depth_optical_frame at time
1.30503e+09 according to authority unknown_publisher Possible reasons are listed at http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained
         at line 260 in /Users/usr/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometry_experimental/tf2/src/buffer_core.cpp
```

According to that wiki entry, one would send an Empty message the topic /reset_time. However, it seems that this topic has been removed a long time ago. What is the currently recommended way to deal with this time reset problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206748/tf_old_data-ignoring-data-from-the-past-for-frame-openni_depth_optical_frame/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2015-04-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you publishing the clock? More recent tf implementations clear the buffer when negative time jumps are detected.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2015-04-07**:
Yes, I am publishing the clock, also sim_time is being used.

**Comment by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on 2015-04-20**:
/clock is definitely being published, but it seems to hang from time to time. This may be related to my question http://answers.ros.org/question/200539/rosbag-play-stuck-tf-issues/?comment=200592#comment-200592

**Comment by [dmurphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/27352/dmurphy/) on 2016-06-30**:
Hi J.M.T., did you figure this out? I have a very similar issue. The weird thing is that for me it all works, so the tfs are being published, but I just get lots of these TF_OLD_DATA messages cluttering up my terminal.